# Jfree chart - Include pan functionality in browser

Tags: java, web, jfreechart

Hi I am trying to make a dynamic stacked area and time series chart using jfreechart. I want to display it on a browser. Also, I want the pan and zoom using mouse wheel functionality. Any idea, how this can be done? Is it even possible ?

Or is there any other library by which I can make the chart?

Comment: You could try deploying via [tag:java-web-start], but you may want something like [this](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/zooming-panning/).

Answer (score 0):

- In order to zoom in your *chart*, you need to implement [`Zoomable`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/Zoomable.html) interface.
- In order to pan your *chart*, you need to implement [`Pannable`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/Pannable.html) interface.

Rather than using *JFreeChart*, you can use the new Java way to draw charts *JavaFX*. Check this tutorials [Using JavaFX Charts](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/jfxpub-charts.htm).

Comment: I set the options of setDomainPannable() and the setRangePannable() to be true. Still doesn't work. I guess, I cannot render the chart as an image and still expect the chart to have these functionalities. 

Any insight on that ?

Comment: Also, does JavaFX give you pan and zoom using mouse wheel functions ?

Comment: I have no idea about the new functionalities of JavaFX. You have to give it a try by yourself. But about the Zoom or Pan just try to implement those two interfaces ....

Comment: How do I do it on a browser? I am able to do it on a normal JFrame.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add HTML content to your JFrame ? you can do that using JavaFX, check this article https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/overview.htm

Comment: Is this what your are looking for ?

Comment: I guess I phrased my question wrong. You said I'd have to implement the Zoomable and Pannable interfaces for Jfreechart.  Well, I have done them . I have my chart in a chart panel. Everything works fine when I run the application using a JFrame. 

What I would need is for the chart to be shown on a browser with the zoom and pan functionalities.

Comment: but this is another question ! You have to ask it ... it is an interesting one, but about the current question, I think I have done my best :)

Comment: So it is the inverse you are looking for , not to include the Web html based component in a desktop app but rather include the jfreechart (or javafx) in a browser ... ?

Comment: if I well understood this part of your question, I have no idea how to answer it, good luck

Comment: You got it correct ! include my chart in a browser! Thanks anyway!